# Установить cookie средставми JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно установить cookie средставми JQuery

HTML

```
 <a href="#" onclick="cat('a');">A</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="cat('b');">B</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="cat('c');">C</a>
```

JS

```
 function cat(value) {
     switch (value) {
     case "a":
          cookie('cat', value);
     break;
     case "b":
          cookie('cat', value);
     break;
     case "c":
          cookie('cat', value);
     break;
     default:
          cookie('cat', null);
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции для работы с cookie можно взять например [тут](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#3-2-i-1-getcookie-setcookie-deletecookie)

В вашей функции можно обойтись без switch

```
function cat(value) {
    setCookie('cat', value);
};
```

Или прямо в разметке

```
<a href="#" onclick="setCookie('cat', 'C');">C</a>
```

Но события лучше привязывать не в разметке:

```
<a href='#'>A</a>
<a href='#'>B</a>
<a href='#'>C</a>
```

и код js

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    setCookie('cat', val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть плагин: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Установка:

```
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

Установить куки:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```